# Simple PHP request to retrieve and echo 'products' from cart not working?

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, while-loop, shopping-cart

Trying to use the `while loop` to echo the `prod_qty` and `prod_desc` fields from database. **Getting no errors.** I've also tried using the `foreach loop` as you can see in the code, yet **it doesn't display anything.**

Here is the cart.php file:

```
    <?php
// 1. Establish a connection using three functions: 1. mysqli_connect() 2. mysqli_connect_errno() 3. mysqli_connect_error()
    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbuser = "root";
    $dbpass = "";
    $dbname = "shoppingcart";

    $connection = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname); 

    // Test if connection occured
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        die("Database connection failed " . mysqli_connect_error() . "( " . mysqli_connect_errno() . " )");
        }    


    // Show the products by performing a query to database.
    $query = "SELECT prod_desc, prod_qty FROM cart WHERE prod_id = 1 AND prod_id = 2 AND prod_id = 3 ";

    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    while($cart = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $cart["prod_qty"];
        echo $cart["prod_desc"];

    }

    /*if($result) {

        foreach ($result as $cart ) {
            echo $cart["prod_qty"];
            echo $cart["prod_desc"];

        }

        } */

?>
```

Here is my database structure:

[image]

[image]

I'm sure I am making a silly mistake because I got no errors! Any ideas guys?

Comment: logic error prod_id cant be 3 things at once. did you mean **OR** not *AND*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you wanted to get records having `prod_id` 1 or 2 or 3 you can use `in` as below :

```
$query = "SELECT prod_desc, prod_qty FROM cart WHERE prod_id in (1, 2, 3 )";
```

Comment: Thank You! Note you forget to add " before semicolon.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use AND for the same column.

Change this :

```
$query = "SELECT prod_desc, prod_qty FROM cart WHERE prod_id = 1 AND prod_id = 2 AND prod_id = 3 ";
```

to

```
$query = "SELECT prod_desc, prod_qty FROM cart WHERE prod_id = 1 OR prod_id = 2 OR prod_id = 3 ";
```